# Typescript error when trying to remove event with FormEvent type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to remove an event listener but I am getting an error in Typescript because removeEventListener expects the type EventListenerOrEventListenerObject but the type of this event handler is of FormEvent:

```
private saveHighScore (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
```

This is how the event is being removed:

```
window.removeEventListener('click', this.saveHighScore);
```

Error message:

`TS2345: Argument of type '(event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
  Type '(event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerObject'.
    Property 'handleEvent' is missing in type '(event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void'.`

So what would be the correct way to remove a react FormEvent?

**Update:**
I am adding this event like this:

```
<input onClick={this.saveHighScore} className="btn btn--high-score" type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

Comment: Are you using `window.addEventListener` already? If so, how?

Comment: With a onClick on a input element (see update in post).

Comment: `onClick={this.saveHighScore}` uses React's internal event handling; it's entirely separate from the actual DOM's event listener handling.

Comment: There are ways around your typing issue but I'm confused why you want to try and manually remove this event listener. Do you have a specific reason?

Comment: So people won't be able to double save form data by double clicking. setting the button on disable wasn't a soothing solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler is managed in React, so keep the management there. If adding the listener should be conditional, then manage it in the `render` method. Something like the following:

```
saveHighScore = () => {
  this.setState({
    scoreSaved: true,
  });
}

render() {
  const onClickHandler = this.state.scoreSaved ? null : this.saveHighScore;
  return (
    <input onClick={onClickHandler} className="btn btn--high-score" type="submit" value="Save"/>
  );
}
```